# HttpClient no success status code

Tags: c#, httpclient

I am trying to access this [link](https://animedao.pw/watch-online/toaru-majutsu-no-index-ii-episode-15/) through `HttpClient` but every time it says that `IsSuccessStatusCode` is `false`. In the past I was able to get the content but now it wont work. It gives me `302` response code.

the code that I am trying is:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                AllowAutoRedirect = false,
                UseCookies = true,
                PreAuthenticate = true,
                UseDefaultCredentials = true
            };
            var client = new HttpClient(handler);
            //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0");
            var data = await client.GetAsync(Url);
            if (!data.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                ;
            }
            var doc = new HtmlDocument();
            var content = await data.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here and how can I make it work? So I can get the content. Thanks
P.S. I have the permission of the website owners to use the website.

Comment: Try browsing the link in browser and while fiddler is opened and see what status code you see in fiddler.

Comment: What am I looking for in the Fiddler? I cant seem to find anything. It loads with `200` code in browser but in the app the code is not success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Quick Solution

```
AllowAutoRedirect = false // change this to true
```

---

### What's going on with the `IsSuccessStatusCode`?

Let's start by looking at the **HttpResponseMessage Class** for the implementation of the `IsSuccessStatusCode` property.

```
public bool IsSuccessStatusCode
{
    get { return ((int)statusCode >= 200) && ((int)statusCode <= 299); }
}
```

> As you can see, the **302** status code in will return a `false`.

---

### 302 Status Code

**The requested resource resides temporarily under a different URI.** Since the redirection might be altered on occasion, the client SHOULD continue to use the Request-URI for future requests. This response is only cacheable if indicated by a Cache-Control or Expires header field.

The temporary URI SHOULD be given by the Location field in the response. Unless the request method was HEAD, the entity of the response SHOULD contain a short hypertext note with a hyperlink to the new URI(s).

If the 302 status code is received in response to a request other than GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect the request unless it can be confirmed by the user, since this might change the conditions under which the request was issued.

*Source: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.3*

Comment: is there a solution to the problem?

Comment: if I change it to true, there is another error that redirect will change the secure method to unsecure and the status code is still 302. I can access the other website fine just not the videos page of any anime.
It is also throwing an exception now that "An error occurred while sending the request."

Comment: @Ahmar - You should open up another question regarding your new error as this answer seeks to solve your issue of 302 not being handled properly.

Comment: I found it out using Fiddler that there was indeed some content regarding the redirection url and it pointed to a new location but it was encrypted so HttpClient was unable to handle it. But thanks for the efforts.